# Inverse Fourier Transform and the sign of the Shifted Delta

Tags: fourier-analysis, integral-transforms

I am using the sign convention of `FourierParameters->{0, -2 Pi}` for calculating the inverse FT of $Aexp(-2\iota\pi f K)$, where $A$, $K$ are real numbers >0 and $f$ is the frequency.

`S = InverseFourierTransform[A E^(-2 I f K \[Pi]), f, x, FourierParameters -> {0, -2 \[Pi]},  Assumptions -> {Element[A | K, Reals], K > 0, A > 0}]`

The answer is `A DiracDelta[K - x]`, however if we put a real value of K, say 5,

`S = InverseFourierTransform[A E^(-2 I f 5 \[Pi]), f, x, FourierParameters -> {0, -2 \[Pi]},  Assumptions -> {Element[A, Reals], A > 0}]`

The answer is `A DiracDelta[-5 + x]`

Why do we see a difference in the sign of x when we have already specified that K is a real number greater than 0? The DiracDelta is said to be even, but can we still get general answer `A DiracDelta[-K + x]` in Mathematica, without inserting a real positive constant in place of K.  I have tried GenerateConditions but still the general answer is `A DiracDelta[-K + x]` instead of `A DiracDelta[K - x]`.

Comment: delta is "on" only when its argument is zero. Right? In the first case this happens when $x=k$. Correct?  In the second case, it is "on" when $x=5$. This makes sense since you put $k=5$. So I do not know see any issue? There is no difference if you write $-k+x$ or $k-x$ in both cases you get $x=k$ in order for the delta argument to be zero.

Comment: `DiracDelta[a] = DiracDelta[-a]`, so `DiracDelta[x - 5] = DiracDelta[5 - x]`.  Either is correct.  Whichever form Mathematica chooses, it generally outputs variables in expressions in alphabetical order.

Comment: I agree both answers are correct but if we replace K with another letter, c, it is still DiracDelts[-c+x]. I was wondering about the sign associated with x.

Comment: Both `DiracDelta[x-5]` and `DiracDelta[5-x]` mean the $\delta$-distribution with the support at $x=5$.

Answer (score 1):

I can't say I always understand Mathematica's formatting rules, but you do have some choices.  You probably have your default output format set to `StandardForm`. Maybe you would like `TraditionalForm` better.

```
S = InverseFourierTransform[A E^(-2 I f K \[Pi]), f, x, 
  FourierParameters -> {0, -2 \[Pi]}, 
  Assumptions -> {Element[A | K, Reals], K > 0, A > 0}]
```

$A\  DiracDelta[K-x]$

```
S = InverseFourierTransform[A E^(-2 I f K \[Pi]), f, x, 
   FourierParameters -> {0, -2 \[Pi]}, 
   Assumptions -> {Element[A | K, Reals], K > 0, A > 0}] // 
  TraditionalForm
```

$A\  \delta (K-x)$

In the case of `5` in place of `K`

`StandardForm`

$A\  DiracDelta[-5+x]$

`TraditionalForm`

$A\  \delta (x-5)$

My earlier comment about variables in alphabetical order applies to `StandardForm`.  `TraditionalForm` operates under different rules and I don't pretend to know all of them.

I would expect the variable `c` to behave the same as `K` because they are both ahead of `x` in the alphabet.  Try `y` instead because it is after `x`.

`StandardForm`

$A\  DiracDelta[-x+y]$

`TraditionalForm`

$A\  \delta (y-x)$

As to which variable it makes negative, I cannot predict, but both ways are correct for `DiracDelta`.  Outputting to `TraditionalForm`, unlike `MatrixForm` and other formatting options, does not ruin the ability to use the results in further calculations.

While I use `StandardForm` for input, since Version 3 I have used `TraditionalForm` as my default output format, but I realize that is not for everybody.  The only problems I have seen is using the `Notation` package, since that requires both input and output formats to be the same.

Comment: Okay thanks . I have also written to Mathematica. Let us see what they respond.